# uwp deferred loading of image sources

Tags: c#, asynchronous, uwp, async-await, deferred

A UWP app, a collection of view models is instantiated and populated in the page's constructor. Each item has a property called `ImageSource` of type `BitmapImage`, initialized to a new `BitmapImage()`. The view has a Grid View bound to the collection. In the view, a `DataTemplate` is defined for the items of the collection. The `DataTemplate`, in particular, shows an image whose source is bound to the item's property `ImageSource`. The `DataTemplate` also handles events of Image, so it displays a placeholder while the image is still loading.
The page's Loaded event triggers the download of all image source:

```
        private async void Page_Loaded(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (ImageViewModel imageViewModel in this.imageViewModels)
            {
                IRandomAccessStream randomAccessStream = await SlowImageSourceProvider.GetRandomAccessStream(imageViewModel.Id);
                await imageViewModel.ImageSource.SetSourceAsync(randomAccessStream);
            }
        }
```

In this code, an instance of `IRandomAccessStream` is retrieved from a slow provider, like an `HttpClient` listening on a slow network.

The Image.Source on the view are bound to the `imageViewModel.ImageSource` of the code above. In such a way, each image needs to wait for the previous one to end its downloading, before starting to download its own source.

How is it possible to make all images to start downloading at once, without them to wait for the others?

The only idea I had was to create a lazy implementation of IRandomAccessStream, but I wander if there is a better way of doing it.

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at `ImageEx` Control from [UWP Community Toolkit](http://www.uwpcommunitytoolkit.com/en/master/controls/ImageEx/). Maybe this will help.

Comment: Thanks. The ImageEx has facilities to show a placeholder while image is loading, but seems not to address the problem of loading sets of images in an asynchronous and efficient way.

Comment: Well, My App downloads 50 Images of size ~300 KB Each as sets without hanging the screen and Loads them in my `GridView` with Lazy Implementation. Try the sample App and see if it suits your requirement.

Comment: The point, here, is that it requires, let's say, 10 seconds to await the stream: IRandomAccessStream randomAccessStream = await SlowImageSourceProvider.GetRandomAccessStream(imageViewModel.Id);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The images will only download one at a time because the `foreach` will not start another iteration until both `await` statements complete. To request all images download concurrently and wait for them to complete asynchronously try the following:

```
private async void Page_Loaded(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e) {
    var setImageTasks = this.imageViewModels.Select(async imageViewModel => {
        var randomAccessStream = await SlowImageSourceProvider.GetRandomAccessStream(imageViewModel.Id);
        await imageViewModel.ImageSource.SetSourceAsync(randomAccessStream);
    }).ToArray();
    await Task.WhenAll(setImageTasks);
}
```